# PHP function with parameter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, get

I am trying to execute a php  "runMyFunction($para)" function which takes in a string parameter when clicking on an image

```
 echo '<a href="index.php?similair=true"><img src="'. $location. '" alt="'. $name, '"     />';
```

and my php funtion is

```
 function runMyFunction($input) {
    echo  $input;
  }

  if (isset($_GET['similair'])) {
    runMyFunction();
  }
```

My question is how can I pass another string value so I can use it inside the `$_GET` checking part to pass it as a parameter in my function

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried putting a parameter inside a link (something like that `"index.php?similair=true&amp;" . $input`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a second  parameter named param2 and you want pass the value 'test'

```
echo '<a href="index.php?similair=true&param2=test">
            <img src="'. $location. '" alt="'. $name, '"     />';


  function runMyFunction($input) {
      echo  $input;
    }

    if (isset($_GET['similair'])) {
      runMyFunction( $_GET['param2']);
    }
```